# Angularjs controller is showing undefined?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, controller, cassandra

I am working on node app using angularjs and cassandra. 
when i go to page such as register page then front end is coming appropriately but it is showing error that controller is undefined.
**Error: error:areq
Bad Argument**

this is app.js (main js configuring file)

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider',
    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/browser/views/home.html'
            })
            .state('register', {
                url: '/register',
                templateUrl: '/browser/views/register.html',
                controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: '/browser/views/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            })
    }
]);
```

this is register.html file  followed by the path of controller.

```
<div ng-controller="RegisterCtrl" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row custom-row2">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
        <h4 class="sign_up">{{ title }}</h4>
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="login_form" name="login_form" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input ng-model="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="field1" id="name" aria-describedby="inputSuccess3Status" placeholder="Enter Your Name....">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**this is the registerCtrl.js file which is coming on checking in firebug**

```
 angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
    .controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope',
        function($scope, RegiserService) {
            $scope.title = "Sign Up";
        }
    ]);
```

but **title** which has to come from the registerCtrl controller is not coming and  **{{ title }}** is coming in that place.

i have gone through several times through this but didn't able to get what is going wrong in defining controller.

Comment: You are recreating the app again by doing `angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).controller`. Just use the getter syntax `angular.module('app')` to get the module once the app has been created.

Comment: i didn't get you? please explain ??

Comment: I have added answer with explanation with documentation link.. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are recreating the module again by doing `angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).controller.` Just use the getter syntax `angular.module('app')` to get the module once the app has been created. I am assuming you are doing the same while registering the service `RegiserService` which cleans up anything else registered to the same module `app`. Once the module has been created by using the syntax `angular.module('moduleName', [..dep])` you should just get the module with the getter syntax `angular.module('app')` while registering any other subsequent entities.

Module creation (Just once):

```
angular.module(moduleName, [requires], [configFn]);
```

Module Getter (to access already created module):

```
angular.module(moduleName);
```

See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

> When passed two or more arguments, a new module is created. If passed only one argument, an existing module (the name passed as the first argument to module) is retrieved.

So for example:-

```
 angular.module('app').controller('RegisterCtrl',...
 angular.module('app').service('RegiserService',...
```

Comment: You can do that as well and use `app` but you will be polluting global namespace. Instead you could just use the getter syntax as i have mentioned `angular.module('app').controller...;`. You would create the module with the syntax `angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])` just once. Does that clarify?

Comment: i have tried that but controller is still undefined.

Comment: @ashish__k It is pretty simple and basic. You must be redefining the module else where. We cannot only help based on what you show us. Also you need `ng-app="app"` in your html. There could be many other things that could go wring apart from what we are showing us.

Answer (score 1):

Along with redefining module as mentioned by PSL,
One more point is - what is `RegiserService`? If it is some service then the definition of controller is wrong.

correct definition is

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
    .controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', 'RegiserService',
        function($scope, RegiserService) {
            $scope.title = "Sign Up";
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: that is for further use not used in the above given part.

Comment: but then it should be available as service already and appended after `scope` or you should remove it from controller definition.

Comment: yeah it is present not shown above as i have written only partial code for giving idea of nature of problem.